django project on macbook pro M1 pro crashed with illegal hardware instruction

environment: 16-inch，2021
cpu: Apple M1 Pro
mermory: 16 GB
os version: 14.4.1 (23E224)
python version:  2.7.15

Heading
i try to run "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080", but i got illegal hardware instruction.(history project on my company is using python2.7&Django==1.11.29)

below is the traceback on osx system report(you can see full trackback here: https://pastebin.com/Tzdy29Jk);

-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               python2.7 [20108]
Path:                  /Users/USER/*/python2.7
Identifier:            python2.7
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Translated)
Parent Process:        zsh [19681]
Responsible:           pycharm [750]
User ID:               505

Date/Time:             2024-05-04 23:55:26.3734 +0800
OS Version:            macOS 14.4.1 (23E224)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        5CBB7AC0-C198-33B7-4503-8B049D36B4D6

Sleep/Wake UUID:       AC988E56-79A2-4466-AAD1-47F1578D8084

Time Awake Since Boot: 22000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       3855 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Notes:
PC register does not match crashing frame (0x0 vs 0x10CD53688)

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 4 Illegal instruction: 4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [20108]

Error Formulating Crash Report:
PC register does not match crashing frame (0x0 vs 0x10CD53688)

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   corecext.so                            0x10cd53688 initcorecext + 9048
1   libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe9df6 _PyImport_LoadDynamicModule + 150
2   libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe848f import_submodule + 319
3   libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe7ebe load_next + 270
4   libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe6c9b PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 939
5   libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfbd0d7 builtin___import__ + 151
6   libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc9e06 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 27846
7   libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2eb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2147
8   libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfd054a fast_function + 106
9   libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc9889 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 26441
10  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2eb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2147
11  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfd054a fast_function + 106
12  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc9889 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 26441
13  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2eb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2147
14  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfd054a fast_function + 106
15  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc9889 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 26441
16  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2eb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2147
17  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfd054a fast_function + 106
18  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc9889 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 26441
19  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2eb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2147
20  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfd054a fast_function + 106
21  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc9889 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 26441
22  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2eb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2147
23  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2642 PyEval_EvalCode + 34
24  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe5556 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 230
25  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe8a6d load_source_module + 1069
26  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe848f import_submodule + 319
27  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe7ebe load_next + 270
28  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe6c9b PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 939
29  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfbd0d7 builtin___import__ + 151
30  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cf10ce1 PyObject_Call + 97
31  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc8111 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 20433
32  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2eb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2147
33  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2642 PyEval_EvalCode + 34
34  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe5556 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 230
35  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe8a6d load_source_module + 1069
36  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe8e46 load_package + 390
37  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe848f import_submodule + 319
38  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe7ebe load_next + 270
39  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe6c1b PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 811
40  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfbd0d7 builtin___import__ + 151
41  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cf10ce1 PyObject_Call + 97
42  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc8111 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 20433
43  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2eb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2147
44  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2642 PyEval_EvalCode + 34
45  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe5556 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 230
46  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe8a6d load_source_module + 1069
47  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe848f import_submodule + 319
48  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe7ebe load_next + 270
49  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe6c9b PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 939
50  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfbd0d7 builtin___import__ + 151
51  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cf10ce1 PyObject_Call + 97
52  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc8111 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 20433
53  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2eb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2147
54  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2642 PyEval_EvalCode + 34
55  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe5556 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 230
56  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe8a6d load_source_module + 1069
57  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe848f import_submodule + 319
58  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe7ebe load_next + 270
59  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe6c9b PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 939
60  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfbd0d7 builtin___import__ + 151
61  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cf10ce1 PyObject_Call + 97
62  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc8111 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 20433
63  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2eb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2147
64  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2642 PyEval_EvalCode + 34
65  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe5556 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 230
66  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe8a6d load_source_module + 1069
67  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe848f import_submodule + 319
68  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe7ebe load_next + 270
69  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe6c9b PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 939
70  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfbd0d7 builtin___import__ + 151
71  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cf10ce1 PyObject_Call + 97
72  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc8111 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 20433
73  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2eb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2147
74  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2642 PyEval_EvalCode + 34
75  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe5556 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 230
76  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe8a6d load_source_module + 1069
77  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe848f import_submodule + 319
78  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe7ebe load_next + 270
79  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfe6c9b PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 939
80  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfbd0d7 builtin___import__ + 151
81  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc9e06 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 27846
82  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2eb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2147
83  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfd054a fast_function + 106
84  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc9889 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 26441
85  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2eb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2147
86  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cf3da84 function_call + 388
87  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cf10ce1 PyObject_Call + 97
88  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cf225d4 instancemethod_call + 180
89  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cf10ce1 PyObject_Call + 97
90  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cf7ba5f slot_tp_init + 175
91  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cf7774c type_call + 300
92  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cf10ce1 PyObject_Call + 97
93  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc97b6 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 26230
94  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2eb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2147
95  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfd054a fast_function + 106
96  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc9889 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 26441
97  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2eb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2147
98  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cf3da84 function_call + 388
99  libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cf10ce1 PyObject_Call + 97
100 libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cf225d4 instancemethod_call + 180
101 libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cf0aec0 PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs + 464
102 libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cf7ad32 slot_tp_getattr_hook + 562
103 libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc7abd PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 18813
104 libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfd0631 fast_function + 337
105 libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc9889 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 26441
106 libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfd0631 fast_function + 337
107 libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc9889 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 26441
108 libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfd0631 fast_function + 337
109 libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc9889 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 26441
110 libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2eb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2147
111 libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfd054a fast_function + 106
112 libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc9889 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 26441
113 libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2eb3 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2147
114 libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cfc2642 PyEval_EvalCode + 34
115 libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cff4901 PyRun_FileExFlags + 161
116 libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10cff435f PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 847
117 libpython2.7.dylib                     0x10d00cdfb Py_Main + 3483
118 dyld                                   0x20446b366 start + 1942

Thread 1:: com.apple.rosetta.exceptionserver
0   runtime                             0x7ff7ffd5c494 0x7ff7ffd58000 + 17556
[text](https://stackoverflow.com)


i want to run project on my mac successfully
